# Ajax php validate no function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Below is my html, I need input dialog without form format.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        var username;

        function myFunction() {
            //input dialog
            username = prompt("Please enter your name", "");
            if (username != "") {
                checkNameValidate();
            } else {
                alert("The name is empty, please insert your name");
            }
        }

        function checkName() { //ajax to validate.php
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "validate.php?username=" + username, false);
            xmlhttp.send(null);

            //doFunction();
        }

        function doFunction() {
            //function
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Name" />
</body>

</html>
```

below is validate.php code, my database name is testajax,

```
<?php
    $username=$_POST["username"];

    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("testajax");

    $query1 = mysql_query("select * from user where name='$username'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query1)>0){
            echo "<script language=javascript>alert('The name have used');</script>";
            }
    ?>
```

This is my work, but cannot validate user, what is my wrong, anyone can help correction?

Comment: but cannot validate user is not enough to understand whats happening. can you explain what you expect and what its doing .?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change in your php code ($_POST to $_REQUEST) like,

```
<?php
   $username=$_REQUEST["username"];
```

And call function `checkName()` not `checkNameValidate()` in your javascript code.

And you need to add onreadystatechange function for your response try the below code,

```
var xmlhttp;
function myFunction() {
    username = prompt("Please enter your name", "");
    if (username != "") {
        checkName(username);
    } else {
        alert("The name is empty, please insert your name");
    }
}
function checkName(username) { //ajax to validate.php

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "validate.php?username=" + username, false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

And if your are using jquery, then use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Your php code can be better like,

```
<?php
    // for get method not for post
    // check username is set or not
    $username=isset($_GET["username"]) ? $_GET["username"] : '';
    if($username){ // check if username is not empty
       mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
       mysql_select_db("testajax");

       $query1 = mysql_query("select * from user where name='$username'");
       if(mysql_num_rows($query1)>0){
           echo "The name have used.";
       } else {
           echo "Username not exists, proceed.";
       }
    } else {
       echo "Please enter username.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks for you, I'm solved it...
the problem is _REQUEST

Answer (score 1):

You are using `GET` in your `XmlHTTP` request and `$_POST` in `validate.php`.
Please correct that and let me know how it works.

Also your javascript methods are not matching checkNameValidate & checkName.
You need to get the response and do your logic (which I'm not sure what it is).

Refer this: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_response.asp for more details.

Comment: Post this in the comment section. Not an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by XMLHttpRequest.responseText as below but it is not compatible with IE6/7 browsers.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","validate.php?username="+username,false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

You shoul use the JQUERY.

```
$.get("validate.php?username="+username, function(responseText) {
    alert(responseText);
});
```